# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ko')

Tags: anychart

When calling like that i recive an error

```
var chart = anychart.sunburst(data, "as-tree");
chart.tooltip().useHtml(true);
chart.container("mdl_4000_01_a3_chart");
chart.fullScreen(true)
```

It works without fullScreen but graph is very small sized

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ko') anychart-core.min.js:809

Comment: The size of a chart is mostly determined by the size of its container. Try to apply width and height CSS rules to the container. To provide more detailed assistance, expand your initial question with HTML, CSS, and JS code. Ideally - make a fork of a playground demo - https://playground.anychart.com/